# Is there a way in Django to test if a Cookie sent in request.META or request.COOKIES is httpOnly?

Tags: django, http, cookies, request, http-headers

As the title suggests, I don’t think this is possible in Django:latest as of the time if writing, but is it possible to detect if a cookie sent up in the `request.HEADERS` is `httpOnly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instances, you can use [OWASP ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) or [Detectify](https://detectify.com/) to check if the cookies are being set without the HttpOnly flag.

Don't you also forget that in Django, there's settings you can take advantage of by setting to True in your settings.py, for instances

- [LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#language-cookie-httponly)
- [SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY)
- [CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly)

Comment: Hey @Tiago thank you for you considered answer, however, I was more looking to be able to test if a cookie could be tested for httpOnly once it is sent back up to the server (in the `request.headers`).

Answer (score 1):

No. `HttpOnly` is a directive of the `Set-Cookie` *response* header. There is nothing in the `Cookie` *request* header that indicates that. This is a fact about HTTP and not a limitation of Django.

Comment: I thought so. Just seems that if we can't test if a cookie has been created in such as fashion: `import requests` `cookies = {'sessionid': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}` `r = requests.post('http://example.com', cookies=cookies)` then I have no real 100% way of securing a site. That's to say, the cookie I pass down to the client is httpOnly, but if I can't test it is httpOnly coming back the other way, then, I can't tell if it has been modified.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts: `HttpOnly` isn't designed to address that threat vector, it's only meant to keep clients from accessing cookies. Servers don't need that protection because they already have ways of protecting the cookies (e.g. unguessably long session ids, secure message digesting, etc.). `HttpOnly` wouldn't really help them; if a malicious actor knows how to forge a valid session id they don't need to use a cooperating browser; they can just construct the request themselves.